# In Help and Improvement, how can I write an edit summary without commenting

Tags: support, help-improvement, automatic-comments, edit-summary

In the Help and Improvement Queue when I edit a question at the end I'm asked to

> **Explain your edit in a comment**

The text is used as **edit summary** but it's also posted as **comment** on the question.

However on a regular edit (outside the queue) I can just fill the **edit summary** without posting a **comment**.

---

The behaviour is weird because posting a comment and sending a notification to say "fix grammar and typo" or "improve formatting" is useless.

And if I don't type anything the **edit summary** will be something like "added 12 characters in body".

So for now I've been removing the generated comments.

Is there a way to prevent the comments ?

Should I leave them here or maybe not write an edit summary ?

Comment: Continue doing what you're doing, deleting them afterwards, or just leave them. *Don't* stop writing them entirely. (Or just edit the posts from outside the queue because the H&I queue is awful)

Comment: This sounds like a bug... Your edit summary should never get posted as a comment. I've seen edit summaries posted as comments before and wondered how that happened while I deleted the comment. I guess this explains how it happened.

Comment: Does it happen to everyone and all the time or just sometimes ? It seems like it's designed this way since the label, the text input and the placeholder are different than the regular edit function and the label suggests that it's a comment.